# Oracle's JDK RPM doesn't provide "java"

Tags: yum, rpm, java

I have the Oracle RPM for the Java 7 JDK installed on an Amazon EC2 instance.

The Oracle RPMs for Java 7 JDK don't "provide" `java` nor `jre`.  RPM reports that it provides the following:

```
# rpm -q jdk --provides
jaxp_parser_impl
xml-commons-apis
jdk = 2000:1.7.0_51-fcs
```

On this EC2 instance, I want to install the `aws-apitools-as` package.  Using yum results in:

```
# yum install  aws-apitools-as
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package aws-apitools-as.noarch 0:1.0.61.4-1.0.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: jre >= 1.6.0 for package: aws-apitools-as-1.0.61.4-1.0.amzn1.noarch
```

This dependency resolution results in yum wanting to install `java-1.7.0-openjdk`, even though I have a perfectly capable Oracle JDK (and thus JRE) installed.

This problem appears to be squarely the fault of Oracle (at least [this SO person thinks so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19515011/1212960)).

Is there anyway to overcome this deficiency in Oracle's RPM packaging by informing the RPM database that Java *is* already provided?

Comment: "I want to install the aws-apitools-as package." Why? The legacy java tools are being deprecated in favor of the new, python-based [AWS CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which installs with a single command and (thank god) doesn't require a java runtime.

Comment: @EEAA: Ah, news to me.  When I took off OpenJDK before installing the Oracle one, `aws-apitools-as` (and others) were removed as part of that transaction.  I'll look into AWS CLI then ... Thanks.

Comment: It's a *much* nicer tool. It provides a single, consistent interface for all the AWS products. Also, needless to say, it is a *lot* faster (being python-based) than the java tools.